# Precise scaling in Edit mode impossible?

Tags: mesh, edges, scale, snapping, measurement

[[image]
[[image]

I turned on the edge length indicator in Edit mode, but apparently it gives false (rounded) values, since the vertices don't align.

In this example I tired joining 3 tetrahedrons around a 345 Pythagoras triangle, and even though I'm seeing 3,4,5 as edge lengths the last vertex falls short.

I realize there are ways to ensure precision since starting values don't really matter, but still I'm interested since my first attempt failed trying to do it this way.